# How to make automatically save text in QTextEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

How can I make QTextEdit save automatically when I'm done typing?  I do not want it to be saved automatically when writing each letter separately. Rather, it is saved after all writing is completed only.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textedit = QTextEdit()
        self.textedit.textChanged.connect(self.save_text)
        layout.addWidget(self.textedit)

    def save_text(self):
        text=self.textedit.toPlainText()
        with open('mytextfile.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyMainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How do you know when "all writing is completed"?

Answer (score 0):

The trick might be to create a button, once the button is pressed then save the text:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.textedit = QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.textedit)

        self.pushbutton = QPushButton()
        self.pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.save_text)
        layout.addWidget(self.textedit)

    def save_text(self):
        text=self.textedit.toPlainText()
        with open('mytextfile.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyMainWindow()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then once you done writing your text, just click the button and it will save your text.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this idea with the button.. hahahaha I want like this without buttons, same function as QlineEdite "self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(....)",  Anyway thank you very much

Comment: @الزعيم 2084 the [`editingFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal is "emitted when the Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus", but that's obviously not the *exact same behavior* you might want from a QTextEdit (specifically the return/enter case), so, as already requested, clarify what you mean by "all writing is completed".

Comment: I mean when you write any note in QTextEdit it is saved automatically in txt file or in the database, without using any buttons.
There is a textChanged function but it is not suitable because it is executed every time when one character is typed! This can slow down the program! Tell me if this is normal.
In QLineEdit you can use the editingFinished function when all the text is written and loses focus it is saved automatically, but the editingFinished function is not recognized in QTextEdit, if there is an alternative tell me thanks.

Comment: @الزعيم2084 You should edit your question and add all that information. Is losing focus the only time you want to automatically save the text? Another option might be to use a timer to save the text every few minutes. Think things through and try to make your question as clear as possible.